# Hi , i want to install catkin_make , but i have an error , so i want to know could i change package.xml?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, package.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

its my error when i run catkin_make :

```
Base path: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1
Source space: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/src
Build space: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/build
Devel space: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/devel
Install space: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/fatima/catkin_ws1/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/fatima/catkin_ws1/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.16
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner2_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner2_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner2_tutorials)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- beginner2_tutorials: 1 messages, 1 services
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:217 (message):
  **catkin_package() DEPENDS on the catkin package 'message_runtime' which must
  therefore be listed as a run dependency in the package.xml**
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
  beginner2_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:13 (catkin_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/fatima/catkin_ws1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/fatima/catkin_ws1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

and this is my CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner2_tutorials)

## Find catkin and any catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg message_generation)

## Declare ROS messages and services
add_message_files(FILES Num.msg )
add_service_files(FILES AddTwoInts.srv)

## Generate added messages and services
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)
catkin_package( INCLUDE_DIRS include
 LIBRARIES ${beginner2_tutorials} CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime roscpp nodelet)

  ## DEPENDS eigen opencv )
## Declare a catkin package
##catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime std_msgs sensor_msgs)
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES beginner2_tutorials
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime roscpp rospy std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
DEPENDS message_runtime
)
catkin_package()

## Build talker and listener
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(talker beginner2_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(listener beginner2_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
```

ofcourse i change this line to solve this problem but it hasnt been solved :

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES beginner2_tutorials
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime roscpp rospy std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
DEPENDS message_runtime
)
```

its package.xml content :

```
<package><name>beginner2_tutorials</name><version>0.0.0</version><description>The beginner2_tutorials package</description><!-- One maintainer tag required, multiple allowed, one person per tag 
--><!-- Example:  -->
<!-- <maintainer email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</maintainer> 
--><maintainer email="fatima@todo.todo">fatima</maintainer><!-- One license tag required, multiple allowed, one license per tag 
--><!-- Commonly used license strings: -->
<!--   BSD, MIT, Boost Software License, GPLv2, GPLv3, LGPLv2.1, LGPLv3 
--><license>TODO</license><!-- Url tags are optional, but mutiple are allowed, one per tag 
--><!-- Optional attribute type can be: website, bugtracker, or repository 
--><!-- Example: -->
<!-- <url type="website">http://wiki.ros.org/beginner2_tutorials</url> 
--><!-- Author tags are optional, mutiple are allowed, one per tag 
--><!-- Authors do not have to be maintianers, but could be 
--><!-- Example: -->
<!-- <author email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</author> 
--><!-- The *_depend tags are used to specify dependencies 
--><!-- Dependencies can be catkin packages or system dependencies 
--><!-- Examples: -->
<!-- Use build_depend for packages you need at compile time: 
--><!--   <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend> 
--><!-- Use buildtool_depend for build tool packages: -->
<!--   <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend> -->
<!-- Use run_depend for packages you need at runtime: -->
<!--   <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend> -->
<!-- Use test_depend for packages you need only for testing: 
--><!--   <test_depend>gtest</test_depend> -->
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend><build_depend>roscpp</build_depend><build_depend>rospy</build_depend><build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend><run_depend>roscpp</run_depend><run_depend>rospy</run_depend><run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend><!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
<export><!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here 
--></export></package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222002/hi-,-i-want-to-install-catkin_make-,-but-i-have-an-error-,-so-i-want-to-know-could-i-change-package.xml?/) by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-12-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-05**:
Hi , i want to install catkin_make but i couldnt because of an error, i want to know could i change package.xml or not and if not how could i fix this problem? please help

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-12-05**:
Please edit your question, adding your CMakeLists.txt and package.xml contents. The error says you are missing a dependency on message_runtime. Does that make sense?

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-05**:
thank you for reply , i edited my question as you told please help me

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-12-05**:
The error says that the message_runtime dependency is missing from your `package.xml`. Please list its contents, too.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-12-05**:
If you are following a tutorial, please provide a link to it.

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-05**:
this that link :http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-05**:
at first i wanted to run 11.Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++) , i have done every thing but when i want to run `catkin_make` i had many errors i solved them but at last this error with message_runtime couldnt be solved

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-05**:
i think so , but i dont know how to change package.xml and add message_runtime?

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-05**:
i added my package.xml as you told

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should add  `message_runtime` to your `package.xml` file as run dependency. Like;

```
<run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
```

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-12-05**:
That's what I suspected from the error message. But, apparently it's no longer part of that tutorial.

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-05**:
thank you so much Akif and joq i did  `<run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>`but now i have another problem with `nodelet` like previous problem.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-12-05**:
You need to update your question so it lists exactly what you currently have in both those files, then paste in the exact error message.

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-05**:
ok , this is the new link for previous question : http://answers.ros.org/question/222026/hi-when-i-run-catkin_make-i-have-an-error-with-nodelet/

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-05**:
thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had to add the following two lines to make it work in their respective sections of the package.xml file:

```
<build_depend>message_runtime</build_depend>
<exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>
```

Also working on the same tutorial. Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [bhristov](https://answers.ros.org/users/33599/bhristov/) with karma: 11 on 2018-02-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2018-02-07**:
The build depend should have been message_generation.